# How to restart computer with terminal with GUI not working

Tags: command-line

if you have a problem where the computer fails to load the GUI (Graphical User Interface), meaning that if you dont see the taskbar, cannot click on icons, cannot close applicaions, etc, You have to restart your device (device that runs ubuntu such as Desktop and Laptops, Obviously.), or your "Power Off" or your GUI or UI doesn't work, etc, this will be a good solution for you.

I had this instance many times. Linux only loaded in the background and that's it. only the shortcuts worked.

Comment: Why not try and solve the GUI not loading? What version Ubuntu? Give us more details.

Comment: First, help @heynnema help you by giving more information. Then, visit [this](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) site and learn about the SysReq keys. An easy way to remember it is that it's "BUSIER" spelled backwards.

Comment: Oh, now I see... this is really an infomercial... he answered his own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

WARNING: This solution is tested on Ubuntu 16.04 And up. This should work on earlier versions. if not, please look for other solutions.

---

To fix that issue, we need to use something called a CLI interface or Command Line Interface. To open CLI, which is a Terminal, do `Ctrl + Alt + T` and you'll have the terminal up.

Inside of the terminal, restart your device with the `reboot` command or shut it down with using the `shutdown now` command and power back on your device. after booting back into Ubuntu, your desktop will load in as expected. Now you can enjoy your day without even worrying about not knowing how to fix that issue.

If you have important progress to save, and you cannot save because of that issue, well I'm sorry to say that your progress has to be sacrificed for the functionality of your deceive.

Comment: What does "functionality of your deceive" mean?

Comment: when i said "functionality of your device", i meant quite literally ythe functionality of your device - In this Topic/Context of trouble-shooting: To get back the normal state of your device - to get it to its normal working state.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't bring up the desktop environments terminal emulator with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, try the following:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to another tty
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to restart computer

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but I dont think Doing ```Ctrl + Alt + Del``` will solve the issue if the GUI or the buttons dont quite work. It's been a while since i had that tissue.

Comment: It doesn't while you're in your desktop environent, you're right. That's why you need to open the text-only terminal first (`Ctrl + Alt + F3`). Note that this often still works when your DE is not even reacting to the other keyboard shortcuts like `Ctrl + Alt + T` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following commands in TTY mode:

```
init 6
reboot
```